# How to handle for loop with large objects in Rstudio?

Tags: for-loop, matrix, vector, memory-management

I have a for loop with large objects. According to my trial-and-error, I can only load the large object once. If I load the object again, I would be returned the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size *** Mb". I tried to overcome this issue by removing the object at the end of the for loop. However, I am still returned the error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 699.2 Mb" at the beginning of the second run of the for loop.

My for loop has the following structure:

```
for (i in 1:22) {
  VeryLargeObject <- ...i... 
  ...
  .
   .
    .
  ...
  rm(VeryLargeOjbect)
}
```

The `VeryLargeObjects` ranges from 2-3GB. My PC has RAM of 16Gb, 8 cores, 64-bit Win10.

Any solution on how I can manage to complete the for loop?

Comment: did you check or specify the environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "cannot allocate..." likely comes from the fact that **rm() does not immediately free memory**. So the first object still occupies RAM when you load the second one. Objects that are not assigned to any name (variable) anymore get garbage collected by R at time points that R decides for itself.

Most remedies come from not loading the entire object into RAM:

- If you are working with a matrix, create a `filebacked.big.matrix()` with the [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory) package. Write your data into this object using `var[...,...]` syntax like a normal matrix. Then, in a new R session (and a new R script to preserve reproducibility), you can load this matrix from disk and modify it.
- The [mmap](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mmap) package uses a similar approach, using your operating system's ability to map RAM pages to disk. So they appear to a program like they are in ram, but are read from disk. To improve speed, the operating system takes care of keeping the relevant parts in RAM.
- If you work with data frames, you can use packages like [fst](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fst) and [feather](https://cran.r-project.org/package=feather) that enable you to load only parts of your data frame into a variable.
- Transfer your data frame into a data base like sqlite and then access the data base with R. The package dbplyr enables you to treat a data base as a tidyverse-style data set. Here is the [RStudio help page](https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/). You can also use [raw SQL commands with the package DBI](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/)

Another approach is to not write interactively, but to write an R script that processes only one of your objects:

Write an R script, named, say `processBigObject.R` that gets the file name of your big object from the command line using `commandArgs()`:

```r
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
#
# Process a big object
# 
# Usage: Rscript processBigObject.R <FILENAME>

input_filename <- commandArgs(trailing = TRUE)[1]
output_filename <- commandArgs(trailing = TRUE)[2]

# I'm making up function names here, do what you must for your object
o <- readBigObject(input_filename) 
s <- calculateSmallerSummaryOf(o)

writeOutput(s, output_filename)
```

Then, write a shell script or use `system2()` to call the script multiple times, with different file names. Because R is terminated after each object, the memory is freed:

```r
system2("Rscript", c("processBigObject.R", "bigObject1.dat", "bigObject1_result.dat"))
system2("Rscript", c("processBigObject.R", "bigObject2.dat", "bigObject2_result.dat"))
system2("Rscript", c("processBigObject.R", "bigObject3.dat", "bigObject3_result.dat"))
...
```